# Creating git development directory

Tags: git

I've just installed git on my production server and added all my production code under /httpdocs/ to my git repository and committed it.

I've now setup my development webserver to use /httpdocs/dev/ as its HTML root directory and want to use /dev/ as my staging and dev directory.

How do I use git to create a branch on /httpdocs/dev/ such that I can make changes, commit it, and then checkout to my /httpdocs/ folder?

Thanks,
Git Newbie

Comment: Arrowmaster, thanks for the tip! I eventually decided to use github.com as my remote repository - I did have to sign up for the Micro plan ($7/month) so I could have a private repository but I feel it was well worth it to have my code backed and have simple point-click navigation of my repository using github.com.

I also decided to register a new domain, dev-xxxx.com, so I could easily make changes there and push to my github.com private repository.
They also support post-receive hooks so I'm looking into that right now.
http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more on this [webpage](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) for more details but basically you can create a bare repo on your server with `git init --bare` then add a post-receive hook to the bare repo with the following.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/httpdocs git checkout -f
```

Answer (score 0):

"cd /httpdocs/dev", followed by a "git init". Done.

Please read the documentation, they are there to explain how to do these very simple tasks.